# How to add colour classes to this css

Tags: html, css, class, html-lists

I'm basically looking to add colour classes to what I have below. I'm going to be adding more colours so this way obviously won't work for me while being clean. I tried adding in the class below to add to my li's but doesn't seem to work. The css and html are below that.

```
#content ul.icon-text li .orange {
    background-color:#f37028;
}

-------------------------------

#content ul.icon-text {
    width:100%;
    height:2.1vw;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1% 0 0 0;
    background-color:#f37028;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
}

<ul class="icon-text">
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your selector for your first style will select descendents of your `li` which have a class of `orange`, is that what you want? Or do you want the `li` to have the background colour?

Comment: @Chris Hardie - Sorry, should have been clearer. I added the rule above the dotted line just to show what I've tried. It's not in my css when testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are trying to create COLOR classes

```
.orange {
    background-color:#f37028;
}
.silver {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

and so on...

```
<ul class="icon-text">
  <li class="silver">...</li>
  <li class="orange">...</li>
</ul>
```

also possible

```
<ul class="icon-text orange">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

I am not sure if that is what you were asking...

Best of luck, let me know if that is not it so I can delete it :)...

Comment: I'd like to add a custom colour to the same ul but on different pages. I have this working for different elements across my site but need it for this ul specifically. I added the rule (above the dotted line) in my example to work the same way your css did but again it's not doing anything for me. I'm guessing this is a lot more simple than what I'm thinking....

Comment: if you take out .orange from your code above it will add that color to all <li> elements across the site that have class "icon-text" or you can just add "icon-text orange" combination of my code and yours. So that way it will add orange color only to that 1 UL list

Comment: @Compton I just added one more way that I just described to you

Comment: can you please explain what you got under "also possible"? I tried something like this but I've never called css in that way so I definitely screwed up somewhere.

Comment: What you do is you can add multiple classes to 1 element like UL in this case. So I added 2 classes :icon-text: and :orange: class. You need to create the .orange class in your CSS first or what ever color you would like. After you do that you can attach that class to any element in your HTML.

Comment: Again, I'm horrible at explaining myself. I meant to explain how to classes work together. I've never used two classes like you did above. I've figured it out though. Thanks for teaching me something. Works perfectly and this exactly what I was looking for. Thanks boss.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.orange`

should be 
`#content ul.icon-text li`

Answer (score 0):

you defined the `.orange` class but you didn't use it in your HTML code.

```
#content ul.icon-text li.orange {
    background-color:#f37028;
}
```

as per the HTML code you given here should use this line of code.

```
ul.icon-text li {
    background-color:#f37028;
  display:block;
  margin:4px;
}
```

if you want each `<li>` should be in orange color then you can define the class `.orange` and apply to specific `li`.

A Working Demo Link. http://jsbin.com/xagevava/1/edit

Comment: Sorry, I left some html out, including the content div. I figured this would be more straight forward than it is. I also tend to make things more confusing than they need to be. Essentially, I'm looking to add colours to the ul, not the li. I'm also using colour classes like this elsewhere and I need these to be specific for this ul.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x85kG/)

Since your css is taking #content is the parent, your html structure should also involve #content in it to see the orange background for li.

```
<div id="content">
<ul class="icon-text">
<li class="orange">...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I left some html out, including the content div. I figured this would be more straight forward than it is. I also tend to make things more confusing than they need to be. Essentially, I'm looking to add colours to the ul, not the li. I'm also using colour classes like this elsewhere and I need these to be specific for this ul. It updated your js and removed the background colour from #content ul.icon-text and the li is blank so something is up. 

http://jsfiddle.net/x85kG/4/

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x85kG/5/. Here you can add separate classes like .red, .blue, .orange independent of any id and you can still apply it wherever you need, as in applying mulitple classes to the same element like <ul class="icon-text blue">. Here icon-text is one class, and blue is other, if you want to have color  values separate. Hope this helps.